# document.getElementById - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please excuse this extremely trivial question but I just started to experiment a little with Javascript but can't seem to figure out where I went wrong with this.

Uncaught ReferenceError: temperature is not defined

Every little tip is greatly appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/EWX/92,61/forecast/hourly' }).done(function(res) {
var temp = res.properties.periods[0].temperature;
});

function test () {
document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = temp;
}
```

Comment: Your title has a different error than your question. Which is it?

Comment: Use an external script tag in your head like `<head><script type='text/javascript' src='folder/file.js'></script></head>`. On `file.js` it would be like `$(function(){ /* put all your code in here */ });`.

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. The title indicates that jQuery isn't loaded. The error in the question would indicate that you don't have an element by the ID of `temperature` when you run `test()`. The code itself tries to access a variable `temp` that's defined in a different, inaccessible scope.

Comment: Have you imported jQuery? seems like you forgot to add jQuery script.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external script tag in your head like `<head><script type='text/javascript' src='folder/file.js'></script></head>`. On `file.js` it would be like `$(function(){ /* put all your code in here */ });`. Of course, if you want to do something after an asynchronous activity, it must happen then. See the following:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
$(function(){ // jQuery load
$.get('https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/EWX/92,61/forecast/hourly', function(resultObj){
  $('#out').html(resultObj.properties.periods[0].temperature+'&#0176; F');
});
}); // jQuery load end
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px 5px;
}
#out{
 margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    Look in the &lt;head&gt; above then at the jQuery below
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is an asynchronous call. `temp` will always be undefined every time function `test` is called. You can achieve what you wanted by doing the following:

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/EWX/92,61/forecast/hourly' 
    })
    .done(function(res) {
        var temp = res.properties.periods[0].temperature;
        document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = temp;
    });
}
```